# Keep div at the bottom of the page with different screen size

Tags: html, css

I have an html page, the first screen is designed to cover 100% of the screen (both height and width). 
I need to place a certain div at the bottom of the page, but I can't figured out how.

I cannot use position fixed because it's a sort of parallax template, so the div would be covered as soon as the user scroll down the page, if I use margin-top: x, the div would be at the bottom of the page only with certain screen resolution, anyone knows what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Please post the relevant code..

Comment: "the div would be covered as soon as the user scroll down the page" **What?**

Comment: use position:absolute; bottom:0px; in footer div

Comment: @Mooseman 

Take this template as example: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0XLB528

With position fixed the central write (modern parallax blablabla) is overwritten as soon as you scroll down a little bit. That what I meant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add position:absolute; & bottom:0; to your div-style

Answer (score 2):

I've been following this tecnique lately

[how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css](http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/)

it's simple, works in all browsers and doesn't rely on weird hacks.

Provided the HTML structure is this

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The css for a footer with 80px height would be

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;  
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, some useful advice there!